# How can I evaluate and plot the eigenvalues of a non-hermitian matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, model, physics, eigenvalue

I need to evalute a two-level system with a non-hermitian Hamiltonian described by the following matrix. I'd like to plot the real and imaginary parts of the eigenvalues as a function of a1, a2 and g and see how the evolve.

```
H = [[a1 + i\gamma, g],[g, a2 + i\kappa]]
```

[Non-hermitian Hamiltonian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD9Yg.png)

I would like some ideas to model this in Python.

Comment: its been a while, but I assume something along these lines? http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~skyjoy/Two-level%20system.pdf, what I don't get is eq5, det(H-lambda*I)=0. if I knew what the lambda*I matrix was, you would just do a numpy matrix calculation

Comment: It is just a quadratic equation. Solve it and plot it

Answer (score 0):

Let me sketch quick answer. Suppose you denote eigenvalue with *l*.
THen problem of finding eigenvalues for 2 level system is equivalent  of solving

Det([[a1 + i\gamma - l, g],[g, a2 + i\kappa - l]]) = 0

This should lead to quadratic equation with two solution for two eigenvalues. Each solution (l1, l2) would be complex function of the parameters

l1 = l1(a1, a2, \gamma, \kappa, g)

l2 = l2(a1, a2, \gamma, \kappa, g)

Then you could compute them and plot them in any way imaginable